# Autotable willDrawCellHook

Tags: javascript, jspdf

i am creating a report using jspdf autotable, the table is drawn using a html , but when the row counter is greater than 5 i need a new page, so i use the willDrawCell hook function to set it.

```
if (idc>5) {
    doc.addPage();
    doc.setPage(1);
    doc.text("OK");
}
    
doc.autoTable({html:"#listai",startY:60,startX:10,theme:"grid",styles: 
{fontSize:12,valign:'middle',halign:'center',lineColor:[0,0,0],textColor: 
[0,0,0]},columnStyles:{8:{textColor: 
[255,255,255],cellPadding:0,cellWidth:0,fontSize:0.1,overflow:"hidden"}},didParseCell:(data) 
=> {
    if (data.section==='body' ) 
    {if (data.row.index>0) {data.cell.styles.minCellHeight=14} else 
{data.cell.styles.fillColor=200}
    };
},willDrawCell: (data) => {if (data.row.index==5 && data.column.index==0) 
{doc.setPage(2)};data.cell.styles.fillColor=255;},didDrawCell: (data) => {
if (data.section === 'body' && data.column.index === 0 && data.row.index>0) {
  //var base64Img = document.getElementById('incfot').src//
    var ss=data.row.index-1;
    var base64Img = document.getElementById('mg'+ss).src;
    var nx = data.cell.width/2-6;
    ng+=14;
    doc.addImage(base64Img, 'PNG', data.cell.x+nx , data.cell.y+1 , 12, 12);
}
}})
```

In this idc is a row counter... so i've created a page first, and when we are drawing the row #5 i change doc to page #2. I've found a black cell...
[image]

i've tried to change fillcolor using data.cell.fillColor=255 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got using doc.setFillColor(255,255,255)...

original: (it doesn't work)

> doc.setPage(2)};data.cell.styles.fillColor=255;

new version:

> doc.setPage(2)};doc.setFillColor(255,255,255);